# DataTables Columns searchable:false also disables Date-Range Search

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable, datatables

I have a Datatbles Table that looks like this:
[image]

The custom jQueryUI From-To **DatePicker used to work before i had to make the DateTime column "searchable: false"**. I did this because i don't want Date-Time results to be included in Search field filter.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var table = $('#myTable').DataTable({       
...,        
    columnDefs: [
            //column 6 set to "not searchable"" 
            { "searchable": false, targets: [6] }
        ]
....
        $('#from').change( function() { 
        table.draw(); } );
        $('#to').change( function() { 
        table.draw(); } );
} );
```

This is the From-To Date range implementation:

```
//Date Range Picker
$(function() {
$( "#from" ).datepicker({
  onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
    $( "#to" ).datepicker( "option", "minDate", selectedDate );
  }
});
$( "#to" ).datepicker({
  onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
    $( "#from" ).datepicker( "option", "maxDate", selectedDate );
  }
});
});

$.fn.dataTableExt.afnFiltering.push(
    function( oSettings, aData, iDataIndex ) {
        var iFini = document.getElementById('from').value;
        var iFfin = document.getElementById('to').value;
        var iStartDateCol = 6;
        var iEndDateCol = 6;         
);
```

Anyone can figure out what do to have both **From**-**To** and **Search** work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only solution i could find is by overwriting the search method. This will enable search only for columns 0-5, and From-To inputs can still use column 6 for Date Range.

```
$('.dataTables_filter input').unbind().on('keyup', function() {
    var searchTerm = this.value.toLowerCase();
    $.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(function(settings, data, dataIndex) 
        {
            if (~data[0].toLowerCase().indexOf(searchTerm)) return true;
            if (~data[1].toLowerCase().indexOf(searchTerm)) return true;
            if (~data[2].toLowerCase().indexOf(searchTerm)) return true;
            if (~data[3].toLowerCase().indexOf(searchTerm)) return true;
            if (~data[4].toLowerCase().indexOf(searchTerm)) return true;
            if (~data[5].toLowerCase().indexOf(searchTerm)) return true;
            return false;
        })
    table.draw(); 
    $.fn.dataTable.ext.search.pop();
})
```

Comment: I think this is the best solution you can come up with. It is logical that `searchable: false` disables the general filtering, also when filtering is performed by code, so we must alter the default filter method as well.